# Links not active until over effect is done

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I am currently trying to add a hover fade-in effect to my links, and I have accomplished that, but the links are not active for a few seconds while the effect is taking place. I have tried fading in the an img element inside the link instead, but that did not work. I switched .mouseover() to .hover() still did not work.

Here is the code:

```
$(".tabButtons a").mouseover(function() {
 $(this).css("opacity","0");        
$(this).css("background","url(/testsite/assets/templates/tsi/images/sspButtonHover.png)");
$(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);       
});

$(".tabButtons a").mouseout(function() {
$(this).stop();
 $(this).css("opacity","1");
$(this).css("background","url(/testsite/assets/templates/tsi/images/sspButton.png)");
});
```

Any suggestions?? [Here](http://www.tsisupport.com/testsite/managed-services-and-proactive-monitoring.html) is the page where this is happening:(there is a row of large grey buttons in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<span>` tag inside of your `<a>` tag and do all of your animation on your `<span>` tag. Give your `<span>` and `<a>` tags fixed dimensions.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I've actually already tried that. I am going to see if I can get a different result by using fadein() instead of animate()

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tabButtons a").mouseenter(function() {
 $(this).css("opacity","0");        
$(this).css("background","url(/testsite/assets/templates/tsi/images/sspButtonHover.png)");
$(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);       
});

$(".tabButtons a").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).stop(true,true);
 $(this).css("opacity","1");
$(this).css("background","url(/testsite/assets/templates/tsi/images/sspButton.png)");
});
```

Comment: This actually helps with the response time, I made the animation only run for 300 milliseconds as well. Still doesn't click right away, but thanks for the suggestion.